# ternary operator inside printf()

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, printf, conditional-operator

Suppose there is an array of n integers named `a`. we want to print the elements of this array with the following for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", a[i], ":,\n"[_____]);
    }
```

write a logic in the blank without changing anything so that colon (`:`) will print after the first element of the array, if there more than one element, comma is printed in between the others element, and a new line after printing the last element of the array.

if I input `1 2 3`, it must output `1:2,3`

Comment: The trick is that it is the same as having `char str[] = ":,\n";` and then use `str[x]` to select characters. For the 3 element example, `x` will be just `i`. For other arrays, it will be just slightly more complicated. Try it!

Comment: `1+!(1-n+i)-!i` would work.  But why the constraint that you must use indexing?  This looks like (undeclared) homework to me.

Comment: @imtiaz It is implossible to do that using such call of printf printf("%d%c",a[i],":,\n"[_____]); because when i is equal to 0 and n is equal to 1 when you need to output two characters ':' and '\n' instead of one character. You could output the new line character '\n' after the for loop.

Comment: For the last item `(i+1==n)` we want `":,\n"[2]`, else for the first item `(i==0)` we want `":,\n"[0]` and for other cases we want `":,\n"[1]`. The expression corresponding to that must be set inside `[]` resulting as value `0`,`1` or `2`.

Comment: That is a hard-to-read, hard-to-maintain, overly-clever "Look how smart I am!" poor way to solve this problem.  Good code is simple, not "clever-crammed-into-as-small-as-possible". There are much simpler, easier-to-understand, and **maintainable** ways to change a separator character like that.  For example:  1. Use a **string**, not a `char`.  2.  It starts as an empty string `""`.  3.  Print it first, before the data so it doesn't appear on the first iteration.  4.  Then change the separation string as needed in the loop - using `if`/`else` as necessary to select the proper string to use.

Comment: (cont) No one should ever be teaching writing code like that.

Answer (score 3):

You want to solve this question using a ternary expression. Let's first express it in English:

- print `:` after the first element, ie: if `i` is `0` use index `0`;
- print `,` after each successive element, ie: if `i > 0`, use index `1`;
- print `\n` after the last element, ie: if `i == n - 1`, use index `2`;

Note that the last condition should probably be tested first, so a list with a single element `1` prints as `1\n`, but the text of the question suggests otherwise. However, if `:` must always be printed after the first element and `\n` must also be printed after the last element, a list with a single entry should have 2 characters printed after the single element, which is not possible by changing only the expression inside the brackets.

Here is an implementation:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", a[i], ":,\n"[i == n - 1 ? 2 : i > 0 ? 1 : 0]);
    }
```

The last condition `i > 0 ? 1 : 0` is actually redundant and can be simplified as just `i > 0`.

Here is a simplified solution:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d%c", a[i], ":,\n"[i == n - 1 ? 2 : i > 0]);
    }
```